# Access JSON object with non-standard key names

Tags: javascript, json, mediawiki

The MediaWiki API returns JSON with key names like "3314" and "*". These throw errors when i try to access them in the normal way.

```
var ob = {
    "query": {
        "normalized": [
            {
                "from": "DE:OpenStreetMap_License",
                "to": "DE:OpenStreetMap License"
            }
        ],
        "pages": {
            "3314": {
                "pageid": 3314,
                "ns": 200,
                "title": "DE:OpenStreetMap License",
                "revisions": [
                    {
                        "contentformat": "text/x-wiki",
                        "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                        "*": "{{Languages|OpenStreetMap_License}}\n\nSiehe '''[http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright www.openstreetmap.org/copyright]'''.\n\n[[Category:License]]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

There you see the problem: keys named 3314 and *.

My first approach was to use

```
$("#b").val(ob.query.pages.3314.revisions[0].*);
```

This throws an error, of course.

I have it now working with

```
// this works with jquery, but is ugly
$.each(ob.query.pages, function(p, pageobject) {
    $("#a").text(p);
    $.each(pageobject.revisions[0], function(k,v) {
        if (k == "*") {
            $("#b").text(v);
        }
    });
});
```

But that cant be the right way to access a single freaking property named "*".

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x5znr1jv/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like

```
$("#a").val(ob.query.pages['3314'].revisions[0]['*']);
```